# AppleScript error: “Finder got an error: Network file permission error.”

Tags: applescript, mojave, automator

I have an automator script that I use to create an empty file in finder and I've been using it with no problem for about a year. All of a sudden, it's giving me this error:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: "Finder got an error: Network file permission error."

What is this error about?

I'm running Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Catalina solved this problem, and the twin problem I had: [App Store on Mojave: "We could not complete your purchase. cancelled"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391725/app-store-on-mojave-we-could-not-complete-your-purchase-cancelled/391749?noredirect=1#comment537476_391749).